# Scraping content from divs with same class names into arrays [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, transformation

I have been developing JavaScript for a decent time, but Python still feels a bit fresh to me. I'm trying to scrape the content from a simple webpage with Python (basically a product list with different sections). The content is dynamically generated so using the selenium module for this.

The content structure is like this with several product sections:

```
<div class="product-section">
    <div class="section-title">
        Product section name
    </div>
    <ul class="products">
        <li class="product">
            <div class="name">Wooden Table</div>
            <div class="price">99 USD</div>
            <div class="color">White</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Python code for scraping the products:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("website.com")
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.name')
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.price")
colors = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.color')

allNames = [name.text for name in names]
allPrices = [price.text for price in prices]
allColors = [color.text for color in colors]
```

Right now I get the attributes of all products (see below) but I can't separate them from the different sections.

Current outcome 
*Wooden Table, 99 USD, White* 
*Lawn Chair, 39 USD, Black* 
*Tent - 4 Person, 299 USD, Camo* 
etc. 

Desired outcome: 
**Outdoor Furniture** 
*Wooden Table, 99 USD, White* 
*Lawn Chair, 39 USD, Black* 

**Camping Gear**
*Tent - 4 Person, 299 USD, Camo*
*Thermos, 19 USD, Metallic*

The end goal is to output the contents into an excel product list, hence why I need to keep the sections separate (with their matching section title). Any idea how to keep them separate, even though they have the same class names?

Comment: Suggest you look at Beautiful Soup library at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: It seems like it has the functions I would need, thank you!

Comment: BeatifulSoup is very powerful library, but might be an overkill for simpler tasks - another api to learn. Vanilla selenium scraping is quite up for a task like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - to group the products by sections, then start off from a section and locate all elements within it. At least your sample html implies its structure allows it.

Based off your code, here's a solution with explanatory comments.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('website.com')

# a dict where the key will be the section name
products = {}

# find all top-level sections
sections = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.product-section')

# iterate over each one
for section in sections:
    # find the products that are children of this section
    # note the find() is based of section, not driver
    names = section.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.name')
    prices = section.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.price')
    colors = section.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.color')

    allNames = [name.text for name in names]
    allPrices = [price.text for price in prices]
    allColors = [color.text for color in colors]

    section_name = section.find_element_by_css_selector('div.section-title').text

    # add the current scraped section to the products dict
    # I'm leaving it to you to match the name, price and color of each ;)

    products[section_name] = {'names': allNames,
                              'prices': allPrices,
                              'colors': allColors,}

# and here's how to access the result

# get the 1st name in a section:
print(products['Product section name']['names'][0])  # will output "Wooden Table"

# iterate over the sections and products:
for section in products:
    print('Section: {}'.format(section))
    print('All prices in the section:')
    for price in section['prices']:
       print(price)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the exact structure I had in mind but did not know how to go about it.